# Disable Norton IS2012 from monitoring Visual Studio projects

Tags: anti-virus, norton-internet-security, visual-studio-2012

I am currently developing a C++ application in Visual Studio and every couple of minutes I build an executable and try to run it.

It takes a relatively long time and I am pretty sure it's the anti-virus software I use that's the cause - Norton Internet Security 2012. I tried to exclude the executables built by VS, but it seems that Norton treats each build as a separate application.

**Q:** Is it possible to set-up Norton IS so that it doesn't monitor the executables built by me (for instance stop it from monitoring my project directory and any executables that will eventually be created there)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Click **Settings** on the Norton Internet Security main page:

   [image: NIS0]
2. On the **Computer** tab, click **AntiVirus and SONAR Exclusions**
3. Click **Configure [+]** next to **Items to Exclude from Scans** (repeat the steps below for **Items to Exclude from Auto-Protect, SONAR and Download Intelligence Detection** as well):

   [image: NIS1]
4. On the **Scan Exclusions** dialog, click **Add**:

   [image: NIS2]
5. On the **Add Item** dialog, click the Browse button [image: NIS3] and navigate to the folder or file to exclude from scans:

   [image: NIS4]
6. OK your way out